# Linux - how to wait on event without using mutex

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, synchronization

This question is for Linux.
I am looking for an alternative for Windows [EVENT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/event-objects) for Linux.

I have several threads, which perform task + sleep in a loop.
If system is shutting-down I want to signal all threads to exit.

I know about `condition-variables`, but I do not need a `mutex`.
I also do not want to introduce a mutex for these free threads.

So pseudo code will be:

```
void WorkerThreads()
{
    do
    {
        ...do something...

        WaitForEvent(event, timeout);
        if (event happened)
            return;

    }   while (not shutting down);
}

    
main-thread()
{
    ...start threads...
    SetEvent(shutdown);
}
```

Comment: How about a semaphore or a futex?

Comment: You can use an atomic variable(std::atomic_bool needToShutDown) and use that in your while check.

Comment: Why not use a thread safe queue to push and pop events?

Comment: The most lightweight solution is a global variable. `bool GlobalEndOfProgram=false;` in main.cpp, `extern bool GlobalEndOfProgram;` in all interested threads and make your do...while condition `while (!GlobalEndOfProgram);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code doesn't need to be portable to non-Linux UNIXes (such as macOS, FreeBSD), you can use [`eventfd`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html) as a direct replacement for Windows event handles, and [`poll`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) (or [`epoll`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html) if you need something more complicated) as a direct replacement for `WaitForSingleObject`. (On Linux, file descriptors are the equivalent of Windows API `HANDLE`s. They are `int` instead of a pointer, but otherwise they work in a very similar manner.)

The following example program shows how `eventfd` can be used when waiting for a single event:

```cpp
#include <sys/eventfd.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdint>
#include <functional>

// Helper functions
// These somewhat mimic Win32 API, but instead of GetLastError() use errno.

// These kinds of events are always manual reset
// return value < 0 -> error
static int createEvent(bool initialState)
{
    return eventfd(initialState ? 1 : 0, EFD_CLOEXEC | EFD_NONBLOCK);
}

static bool resetEvent(int eventFd)
{
    // eventfd uses 64bit integers for signalling
    uint64_t dummy = 0;
    ssize_t l = read(eventFd, &dummy, sizeof(dummy));
    if (l < 0 && errno != EAGAIN)
        return false;
    // EAGAIN is non-fatal here since that just means that
    // the event was already reset when we were called,
    // which is ok
    return true;
}

static bool setEvent(int eventFd)
{
    // eventfd uses 64bit integers for signalling
    uint64_t dummy = 1;
    ssize_t l = write(eventFd, &dummy, sizeof(dummy));
    if (l < 0)
        return false;
    return true;
}

// timeoutMs < 0: infinite
// timeoutMs > 0: timeout in ms
// timeoutMs == 0: just checks if event was set
// return value: true if event set,
//               false if not within timeout (errno == 0)
//               false if error (errno != 0)
//
// this is just a simple function that waits for a single
// event; you can obviously also use poll/epoll
// to wait for multiple events if you need to,
// and combine that with waiting for data on
// sockets and similar
static bool waitForEvent(int eventFd, int timeoutMs)
{
    struct pollfd pfd;

    int rc = -1;
    errno = EINTR;
    while (rc < 0 && errno == EINTR) {
        pfd.fd = eventFd;
        pfd.events = POLLIN;
        pfd.revents = 0;
        rc = poll(&pfd, 1, timeoutMs);
        // technically we should recalculate the
        // timeoutMs if errno == EINTR here, but
        // since EINTR is a very rare condition,
        // keep it simple at this point
    }

    if (rc < 0)
        return false;

    if (rc == 0 || !(pfd.revents & POLLIN)) {
        errno = 0;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

// End of helper functions

void threadMain(int eventFd)
{
    std::cout << "Separate thread: sleeping for 5s...\n" << std::flush;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds{5});
    std::cout << "Separate thread: setting event...\n" << std::flush;
    setEvent(eventFd);
    std::cout << "Separate thread: exiting...\n" << std::flush;
}

int main()
{
    int eventFd = createEvent(false);
    if (eventFd < 0) {
        int error = errno;
        std::cerr << "Error creating event fd: " << strerror(error) << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    auto thread = std::thread(std::bind(&threadMain, eventFd));

    // wait forever for event
    bool ok = waitForEvent(eventFd, -1);
    if (!ok) {
        // since we have infinite timeout this will only
        // happen on error (but if a finite timeout is
        // specified this may happen when that occurs)
        int error = errno;
        std::cerr << "Error waiting for event: " << strerror(error) << std::endl;
        thread.join();
        return 2;
    }

    resetEvent(eventFd);
    std::cout << "Successfully waited for event, and the event was reset.\n" << std::flush;

    // Check that the event is no longer set
    // (this is just for demonstration purposes)
    ok = waitForEvent(eventFd, 0);
    if (ok)
        std::cerr << "Warning: the event is still set after being reset\n" << std::flush;

    // Clean up stuff
    thread.join();
    return 0;
}
```

A couple of notes regarding the choice of flags: the code above uses both `EFD_CLOEXEC` and `EFD_NONBLOCK` to create the eventfd. `EFD_CLOEXEC` is so that the file descriptor isn't inherited by other programs that are launched by your program, and `EFD_NONBLOCK` sets the eventfd to non-blocking mode, to be able to create something that resembles the semantics of the Win32 API functions. If you remove `EFD_NONBLOCK` then `read()` from the eventfd (as used in the `resetEvent()` helper in above code) becomes blocking, and then there's no direct mapping to the semantics of the Win32 API functions, but it may be useful in other cases. (You *could* create auto-reset Win32 events with that, but *only* if you only ever wait for single events via a blocking `read()`; waiting for multiple events always requires `poll()`/`epoll()`, and those alone will never reset an eventfd.)

If you want to be portable with UNIX systems other than Linux, you can always use a [`pipe()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html), but that's two file descriptors (one for writing, i.e. "setting" the event, one for reading, i.e. "resetting" and waiting for the event).

Answer (score 0):

You can try epoll (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html)

You can create your pollfd based on any file descriptor (you would need to open a dummy file descript for this, maybe with memfd_create()) for each event you need and wait on it with poll()